# How to run a command as root at an Ubuntu server start-up?

Tags: startup, port-forwarding

I use the following simple solution for port forwarding:

```
sudo su
nohup redir --lport 80 --caddr 192.168.1.2 --cport 80 &
```

It works this way and doesn't work any other (like `sudo nohup...` for example).

I'd like this to be done automatically at my Ubuntu 12.04 Server start-up.

Where can I put this?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file /etc/rc.local and put:

> nohup redir --lport 80 --caddr 192.168.1.2 --cport 80 &

Then issue:

> chmod +x /etc/rc.local

After reboot it should work

Comment: That won't run it as root tho.

Comment: Try and put it on root crontab